# Cant sent mail() with if statement

Tags: php, sendmail

Hope someone can help me with this???

```
if (isset($_POST['frame_in']) == "yes") && (isset($_POST['collected1']) == "no") {
mail($mailTo,$subject,$message,$headers); 
}
```

A little more info

Im trying to fire off an automated email when the following is true 'frames_in' = yes and 'collected1' = no

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: No, you haven't provided enough information. Did you get any errors? Does the if statement evaluate as true or false?

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is wrong.  You want to test if the `$_POST` values are set and equal to `"yes"` or `"no"`.  For example:

```
(isset($_POST['frame_in']) && $_POST['frame_in'] ==  "yes")
```

In context of your code with 2 conditions:

```
if ((isset($_POST['frame_in']) && $_POST['frame_in'] == "yes") 
     && (isset($_POST['collected1']) && $_POST['collected1'] == "no")) {
   mail($mailTo,$subject,$message,$headers); 
}
```

Your original code was comparing the return value of `isset()` (boolean `TRUE/FALSE`) to `yes` or `no`, which it would never be.

You also had some incorrect `()` enclosures and a typo.

When developing, always use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` so that your syntax errors are visible on screen.

Comment: You still have a mistake there... If is not properly ended... Your if statement is like `if (A) && (B) {...}` which I think would fall in a syntax error.

Comment: @shadyyx didn't notice the `S` rather than `$`

Answer (score 3):

change S_POST to $_POST for a start :)